# Do we need to drink milk?

Tags: nutrition, milk, dairy

There are many articles that point out how drinking milk is not necessary and it does no good to human health. These articles state that milk is only for babies (only mother's milk) and there is no need to drink any animal milk. One example is found at [this link](http://www.webmd.com/diet/healthy-kitchen-11/dairy-truths?page=2) to a medical page, which says it is based on studies.

I want to know for a fact: if we don't include milk in our daily diet, will it matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You certainly don't require milk in your diet. Those with allergies need to avoid it. The whole thing is about getting the nutrients that the body needs. If you replace them with sufficient alternative sources, you'll be fine.

Don't forget the calcium, the added vitamin D, etc. that's in milk: All very important building blocks for a healthy life.

Addition, I was reminded to cite a source for my answer:

The USDA on milk, appendix # 3-6. The appendix elaborates all the vitamins that are in milk that the body needs. Further down the appendix it states alternative sources for these nutrients. The link to this is [Here](http://www.google.be/url?q=http://www.cnpp.usda.gov/sites/default/files/dietary_guidelines_for_americans/AppendixE-3-6-Milk.pdf&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjqr-qW273KAhXC_g4KHdWNCdoQFggQMAI&sig2=jHCiR5jJlH7JFlvFTqnD3g&usg=AFQjCNFhpm9nC5k-pT-maDd6zPbv-Kuzcg)